# Suppress "Not Valid" Error message when adding text to number field

Tags: vba, validation, ms-access, error-handling, ms-forms

I'm doing the finishing touches of a MS access database, stuff revolving around input validation and error messages. I have restricted PlotSearch.value [textbox] to only accept numbers which works, but entering letters brings up a very ugly error message:

[image]

I was able to successfully do this with a Combobox with the following code:

```
Private Sub CLIENT_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
    Response = acDataErrContinue
    MsgBox ("Error: Value is not in the list")
    CLIENT.Value = ""
End Sub
```

**BUT** ^ is a combobox and not a textbox, there is no event that can be triggered as far as I know.

I've tried:

```
Private Sub PlotSearch_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
End Sub

Private Sub PlotSearch_AfterUpdate()
    On Error Resume Next
End Sub

Private Sub PlotSearch_AfterUpdate()
    If PlotSearch.EOF Then
    MsgBox ("debug")
    Else:
    MsgBox ("works")
End Sub
```

The problem is that the above attempts at fixing it doesn't suppress the error message at all and Its my intention to show my own error message in there. I find it strange that ComboBoxes can have this in the form of *Not in List* but textboxes don't have a event that's equivalent to *Not valid*.

**Edit:**
Adding a validation rule and breaking it shows this error message, which is worse than the other one.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. You say that it works but at the same time it throws an ugly error. Are you trying to insert the error message inside a textbox that accepts only numbers?

Comment: Have you had a look to the `ValidationText`-property of your textbox?

Comment: @KostasK. Hi Kostas, Nice to see you. I have edited my question.

Comment: @FunThomas I have added a <>0 in the textbox ValidationText property and the error message is worse, Its my intention to make this user friendly. Is there a way to change/ignore this and I will add my own message?

Comment: I assume you have set the check to to the `ValidationRule` property. The `ValidationText`  property defined what message is displayed in case the rule is violated.

Comment: @FunThomas No, I'm actually dumb lol. Thanks for pointing that out!